# Update query doesn't work php

Tags: php, mysql

Update query doesn't work with me, there is no errors but it doesn't work
here is my code.

```
<?php 

        $up=false;
        if ( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ) {
           if ( isset( $_POST['FullName'] ) ) {
               $FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
               mysql_query( "UPDATE users SET Full_Name = '$FullName' WHERE User_Name = '$U_N'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
           }

           if ( isset( $_POST['bd'] ) ) {
               $bd=$_POST['bd'];
               mysql_query( "UPDATE users SET DateOfBirth = '$bd' WHERE User_Name = '$U_N'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
           }

           $up=true;
        }

        if ( $up ) {
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>up()</script>";
           echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=pto.php\">";}
        }

?>
```

here is the full code

Comment: Where is `$U_N` defined?

Comment: You are vulnerable to sql injection. Escape your post values and change to mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors being thrown?  Try throwing a "error_reporting(E_ALL);" at the top of the script and check again (and check your error logs as well)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because the variable is not being embedded properly.

Can you try changing your query to this?

```
"UPDATE users SET Full_Name = '{$FullName}' WHERE User_Name = '{$U_N}'"
```

Or

```
"UPDATE users SET Full_Name = '".$FullName."' WHERE User_Name = '".$U_N."'"
```

Also, `mysql_query` is being deprecated. you might want to use `mysqli_query`

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.